# Serve inline PHP with Nginx and PHP-FPM on OpenSuse

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to get inline PHP to work in my website, however sending the html file to PHP-FPM just parses the php and throws the rest of the file away. 
This is part of my nginx config.

```
    location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
        root           /srv/www/htdocs/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9644;
        fastcgi_index  index.html;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I do have html as an accepted file extension in php-fpm.

Adding `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` anywhere in the file without sending the file to php-fpm does not work, however when i do sent `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to php-fpm, everything except phpinfo gets thrown away.

Edit: Figured this out. I had my extensions and server-side includes set up wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my file extension and includes set up wrong. Turns out that html and php server-side includes are different and that file extension had nothing to do with it.

Edit: Can't mark this as answer right now apparently. Guess I'll wait two days.